# Quick and Simple Real Analysis Bound

Tags: real-analysis

Given the inequalities:

$$|f(x) - g(x)| < \epsilon\quad \forall \quad x \in [a,b]$$

and

$$|g(x)| < M \quad \forall \quad x \in [a,b]$$

where $\epsilon > 0$ and $M > 0$.

What is the tightest bound that I can get on $|f(x)|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triangle inequality gives us

$$|f(x)| \leq |f(x) - g(x)| + |g(x)| < \epsilon + M$$

Comment: Thanks! (also: *facepalm*)

Comment: Take for instance $f(x) = x+ \epsilon$, $g(x) = x$. Then we would get above. If additional properties are imposed on f,g we could get tighter bounds.

Comment: Was the "facepalm" because it was obvious or because you expected something better?

Comment: No not at all! This was exactly what I was looking for actually. I just spent a lot of time going in circles trying to show it.

Comment: Your welcome then.